# Why did my winsocks2 send result in 10057 error sometimes?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, winsock2

I did tcp socket connection with normal(?) steps as the code shows below. But send **sometimes** result in **10057** error while server-end printed some log which says connection is in, I have no idea about what's wrong with my code. Any help is appreciated.
 Any information about stable and robust windows socket programming is appreciated.

MSDN description about 10057 error:

> Socket is not connected.A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using sendto) no address was supplied. Any other type of operation might also return this error—for example, setsockopt setting SO_KEEPALIVE if the connection has been reset.

---

PS: Real ip address in below code snippet is replaced by *127.0.0.1*. Code isn't runnable.

```
int connect_to_server() {
SOCKET soc;
SOCKADDR_IN serveraddr;
SOCKADDR_IN clientaddr;
unsigned char buf[1024];

WSADATA wsa;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);

/* create a tcp socket; */  
if ((soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0/*IPPROTO_TCP*/)) <= 0)
{
    LOGFMTF("errcode[-1], create socket fail!");
    return -1;
}

serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

serveraddr.sin_port = htons(9102);
serveraddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

unsigned long mode = 1;  // 1 to enable non-blocking socket
if (ioctlsocket(soc, FIONBIO, &mode) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    LOGFMTF("errcode[-2], ioctlsocket fail.");
    return -2;
}

if (::connect(soc, (SOCKADDR *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) != 0)
{
    /* FIONBIO socket enters here can go run; non-FIONBIO socket enters here stands for real error;*/
    if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
        LOGFMTF("errcode[-3], connect fail.");
        //return -3;
    }

    //return -1;
}

g_client_fd = soc;

LOGFMTT("client_fd[%d]", g_client_fd);
LOGFMTT("connect to server last err[%d].", WSAGetLastError());

return 0;
}

/** send loop; */
DWORD WINAPI send_thread_loop(LPVOID pM) {
LOGFMTT("send thread[%d] start.", GetCurrentThreadId());

for (;!g_to_exit;) 
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&g_send_queue_lock);
    if (g_send_queue.count() == 0) {
        Sleep(Send_Thread_Gap);
    }else {
        LOGFMTT("send one packet.");
        int pakcet_size = g_send_queue.begin()->size;
        char *addr = g_send_queue.begin()->data;
        ::send(g_client_fd, addr, pakcet_size, 0);

        /* ------------!Attention begin------------ */
        LOGFMTT("send last err[%d].", GetLastError());--------> sometimes got 10057 error.
        /* ------------!Attention end------------ */

        delete[]addr;
        g_send_queue.erase(g_send_queue.begin());
    }
}

LOGFMTT("send thread[%d] exit.", GetCurrentThreadId());

return 0;
}

int start_net_thread() {
g_recv_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, recv_thread_loop, NULL, 0, NULL);

g_send_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, send_thread_loop, NULL, 0, NULL);

return 0;
}

int main(){
if(connect_to_server() != 0) 
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("failed.");
    msgBox.exec();
    return -1;
}

start_net_thread();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Flaky connection, connection lost, ignored error code.

Comment: @CodeCaster Maybe I have much homework to do. Is it OK if I ignore this error and try to send again later? I have changed my code to improve it and will test more to see whether it works in my tomorrow's work.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think I missing some important context about my error.  The connection to server, the send thread start and my fisrt try to send login packet to server is line by line.  By now, if first send failed, no more packet will send.  So I have the question in my first reply.  More work need wait until tomorrow. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

> Why did my winsocks2 send result in 10057 error sometimes?

It didn't. At least, there is no evidence that it did.

```
::send(g_client_fd, addr, pakcet_size, 0);
/* ------------!Attention begin------------ */
LOGFMTT("send last err[%d].", GetLastError());--------> sometimes got 10057 error.
```

It isn't valid to call `WSAGetLastError()` *unless* there *was* an error, which in this case would have been signalled by `send()` returning -1. But as you aren't checking for that, there is no evidence here of a problem to be solved, except for your poor coding around `send()`. It should read:

```
if (::send(g_client_fd, addr, pakcet_size, 0) == -1)
{
    /* ------------!Attention begin------------ */
    LOGFMTT("send last err[%d].", GetLastError());--------> sometimes got 10057 error.
}
```

NB The word is spelt 'packet', not 'pakcet'.

Comment: Thank you for figuring it out, I have detailed my answer. This is my first edition. I had changed `send` part to a `loop` like my answer shown when I encountered this question. Hope that you can make me more clear about when **10057 error** could appear and what should my code do.

Comment: This is correct.  `send` returns a value that must be checked without exception.

Comment: No matter how bad is my code, send can result in **10057 error** and it is the point in my case that **I shoudn't stop sending after 10057 error**.

Comment: @JandunCN It happens when the socket is not connected, as per your quotation from MSDN: in other words, when you haven't succeeded in calling `connect()` in prior code. If it happens, it means you either omitted a `connect()` call or ignored its failure. It is therefore evidence of a prior bug, which must be fixed. Merely mindlessly repeating the `send()` is pointless. It won't fix your bug, or magically connect your unconnected socket. Your remark about 'shouldn't stop sending' is incorrect.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. But I am confused, I didn't do anything except changing `send` part code. And my accident bug disappeared after the change. More information will be appended after I catch the culprit.

Comment: @EJP Yes, it is just not connected, because I `ioctlsocket` client socket to **nonblocking mode** before `connect`. Connection maynot completed when `connect` returns, but I immediately start **send thread**. There is a chance that **send thread** `send` data to an unconnected soeckt.

Thank you again for your reply, without which I wouldn&#39;t have reviewed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Hope my shallow answer will help someone.

It turns out to be that I `ioctlsocket` client socket to **nonblocking mode** before `connect`. Connection maynot completed when `connect` returns, but I immediately start **send thread**. There is a chance that **send thread** `send` data to an **unconnected soeckt**.

Like [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx) says, **With a nonblocking socket, the connection attempt cannot be completed immediately.**

PS: `send` may **send** bytes that less than **expected bytes** specified via the third argument of `send`.

```
int remain_size = pakcet_size;
int this_read_cnt = 0;
for (;;) {
    if ((this_read_cnt = ::send(g_client_fd, addr+ pakcet_size - remain_size, remain_size, 0)) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        remain_size = pakcet_size - this_read_cnt;
    }
    else {
        LOGFMTT("send last err[%d].", GetLastError());
    }

    if (remain_size == 0) {
        delete[]addr;
        g_send_queue.erase(g_send_queue.begin());
        break;
    }
}
```